# Check if system tray focused in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java app that has an icon in the system tray.

How can I check if the tray (or tray icon) has current focus?

Tray and TrayIcon don't seem to have .isFocused() or similar.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `TrayIcon` supports both `addMouseListener()` and `addMouseMotionListener()` you should implement your listeners to care about the state of the selection/focus of the `TrayBar`..

you could try to see which events are fired when you focus it or unfocus. It depends on what you want to catch: if you want to see whenever the user hovers onto the icon you should try with `mouseEntered` or `mouseExited`, and so on. `TrayIcon` doesn't inherit from any standard GUI component so I think this is the only way to work with it.

In addition I won't rely too much of making it work cross-platform since probably these kinds of events are fired from the OS and sent to JVM that forwards them to the `TrayIcon` object but I don't know how well this is implemented, just try it out by yourself.